# The order of b-trees

Tags: data-structures, tree, b-tree

I'm studying for an exam, and came up on B-trees. Wikipedia describes a B-tree as a tree where the nodes have at least d and at most 2d keys and therefore at most 2d+1 leafs. For example if d=1, it would have a maximum of 2 keys, and 3 children, making it a 2-3 tree. However this wouldn't allow for example a 2-3-4 tree unless I'm mistaken.

However our material describes a b-tree as a tree where each node has at least t>=2 t-1 keys and at most 2t-1 keys. This would mean that the nodes have an odd number of keys and an even number of children. For example t=2 would have from 1 to 3 keys, and up to 4 children, making it a 2-3-4 tree. On the other hand there couldn't be a 2-3 tree with this notation.

On top of this, there is a notation by Knuth where the d would mean the maximum number of children in a node. This notation would allow both even and odd number of children, allowing both 2-3 trees and 2-3-4 trees.

I know both 2-3 trees and 2-3-4 trees exist.

What is the real notation? Is there a real notation? As an extra question; what is the maximun number of keys in a tree of size h?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read the wiki article a little more closely you'll see that there are two main variants of B-trees (excluding structural variants like B* and B+), one with `t` -> `2t` keys, and one with `t` -> `2t+1` keys.

Translating those variants to #children we have one with `t+1` -> `2t+1` children, and one with `t+1` -> `2t+2` children.

So essentially to answer your question, both 2-3 and 2-3-4 trees are valid trees, each according to a different variant/definition:

2-3 is of the first kind (`t+1` -> `2t+1` children where t=1)

2-3-4 is of the second kind (`t+1` -> `2t+2` children where t=1)

The validity of both variants stems from the fact that both splits and merges (actions done on delete and insert from/into the ADT) are valid:

`t` -> `2t`:

Split.
Happens when we add a new element and a node has more than the max number of keys `2t`
So we have `2t+1` keys, we split the node into two nodes, and push one element to the parent, leaving `2t` keys in the two children, and `t` keys in each child. This is acceptable because the minimum number of keys in a node is indeed `t`.

Merge.
Happens when we delete a key and a node contains less than the minimum number, `t`, and it's sibling is also at the minimum. So we have `t-1 + t` keys in our new merged node, the resulting node must be valid: `t-1 + t = 2t-1 <= 2t`. Great.

So too with `t` -> `2t+1`:

Split.
`2t+2` becomes `t` and `t+1` which is OK.

Merge.
`t-1 + t = 2t-1 <= 2t+1`

Of course there is no difference in running times, it's just a slight implementation difference of little theoretical importance (you can slightly optimise some algorithms with the first variant, but not so much that it will change run-time complexities).

Answer (score 1):

search in google scholar for b tree comer => Ubiquitous B-Tree, Comer, 1979

This is the most cited paper which you find in data structure papers. This paper describes the b tree in detail (how it works, complexity and it variants...). There you should find your answer.

I hope this helps

p.s. cite that paper in the exam if you use a different formula than the taught one :P